# Shell command line arguments

Tags: shell, unix

How to solve below problem.

```
myscript.sh
echo First argument: $1
echo Second argument: $2
for i in $* do
echo $i
done
```

now executing the script:

```
$./myscript.sh "this is" value
First argument: this is
Second argument: value

this
is
value
```

---

When I am printing $1 I am getting the value "this is"
but inside loop first argument coming as "this"

I want when the loop execute it will print

```
this is 
value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the usage of `$*` instead of `"$@"` to get all of the arguments. From [ShellCheck:](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2048)

> $*, unquoted, is subject to word splitting and globbing.
>
> Let's say you have three arguments: baz, foo bar and *
>
> "$@" will expand into exactly that: baz, foo bar and *
>
> $* will expand into multiple other arguments: baz, foo, bar, file.txt
>   and otherfile.jpg

For the desired behavior you can do this:

```
echo "First argument: $1"
echo "Second argument: $2"

for i in "$@"
    do echo "$i"
done
```